# javac classpath option with multiple jar files in current directory causing error

Tags: java, javac

Environment: Windows 7, Java 6.

Trying to compile a .java file with -cp option. The file uses a single jar file that's in the current directory ALONG WITH some other jar files in the current directory.

```
javac -cp ./*.jar MyFile.java
```

doesn't work.

```
javac -cp ./* MyFile.java
```

doesn't work

```
javac -cp ./MyJar.jar MyFile.java
```

works

First two cases, I get a invalid flag error. Can someone explain this behavior?

And I checked if it is spaces issue, there are no spaces anywhere in my full file paths.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847850/using-wildcards-in-java-classpath

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The quoted sources for the two links provided in the comments as well as in the "This question may already have an answer here:", do not completely explain the observed behavior.

> javac -cp ./*.jar MyFile.java

Won't work, because the wildcard * usage in this context differs from normal usage. This can be understood from the documentation. * always represents full file(s) and not partial file names.

> javac -cp ./* MyFile.java

Should have worked. Apparently using double quotes and/or a semi-colon in windows. works:

> javac -cp "./*" MyFile.java
>
> javac -cp ./*; MyFile.java
>
> javac -cp "./*;" MyFile.java
>
> javac -cp *; MyFile.java
>
> javac -cp "*" MyFile.java
>
> javac -cp "*;" MyFile.java

Nowhere in the documention is this important fact mentioned afaik.

So I guess ON WINDOWS 7 64 bit, with java 1.6.0_75 EITHER USE DOUBLE QUOTES OR ALWAYS A SEMI-COLON WHEN USING WILDCARD *

Comment: I didnt have to use quotes I just used C:\share\NetBeansProjects\JLibUser>%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javac src\jlibuser\\*.java -cp ..\JLib\dist\\*

Comment: @KalpeshSoni could be to do with using current directory?

Comment: @KalpeshSoni Couldn't reproduce your behavior. I moved all my jars from current dir to a child dir in it, and still above behavior holds. I need to do either -cp libs/*; or -cp "libs/*"

Comment: Mine is 1.6.0_75-b13 on windows 7 64 bit

Comment: I use `cygwin 2.8`, win 7, and only double quotes `and` semicolon work in case of multiple `jars`.

Answer (score 0):

use backslash in windows?

try

javac -cp .\* MyFile.java

also note [Broken wildcard expansion for Java7 commandline on Windows(7?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195073/broken-wildcard-expansion-for-java7-commandline-on-windows7)

Comment: no luck. I updated my answer. no double quotes but a semi-colon at the end works.