# error : package org.openqa.selenium doesn't exist

Tags: java, command-line, classpath

I was trying to execute a program which is on Desktop from the command line :

```sh
javac 'BrowserStackTest.java'
```

Body of the program:

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
  
import java.net.URL;

public class BrowserStackTest {

}
```

And I got the below error:

```
BrowserStackTest.java:1: error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
                              ^
BrowserStackTest.java:2: error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
    import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
                              ^
BrowserStackTest.java:3: error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
                              ^
BrowserStackTest.java:4: error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
                              ^
BrowserStackTest.java:5: error: package org.openqa.selenium.remote does not exist
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
```

From the error I was able to observe that I am not providing the jars for the execution, but I am unable to provide them due to lack of enough documentation such as where to add the jars for execution of such programs.

Comment: Please don't mind that class is empty

Comment: use -cp option to specify the jars to include like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25025018/javac-classpath-option-with-multiple-jar-files-in-current-directory-causing-erro

Comment: @Nadir Thanks it worked

javac -cp "selenium-2.48.2/selenium-java-2.48.2.jar;selenium-2.48.2/selenium-java-2.48.2-srcs.jar;selenium-2.48.2/libs/*" BrowserStackTest.java

But i got some more info after executing with the above


Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Comment: In Continuation to the above comment
upon executing the class
java BrowserStackTest
Got the below Error
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/Capabilities
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
       
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by:
1- download selenium jar file from [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/) , name should be like "***client-combined-3.141.59.jar***"

2-include the jar file in libs folder.

3-in app build.gradle add below line:

```
implementation files('libs/client-combined-3.141.59.jar')
```